# I cannot access Azure SQL database using query editor. However I can access it using SSMS with the same SQL Server authentication login and password

Tags: azure-sql-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77OGW.png)

I get the error

> Cannot open database "" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user ''.

Comment: what's the login name? Does the login have permission to access the database?

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you set "Allow access to Azure services" to ON on the firewall configuration of your Azure SQL Database.

[image]

Please take in consideration, that Azure AD admin sign in doesn't work with accounts that have 2-factor authentication enabled. In addition, Query editor doesn't support connecting to the master database.