# How to enable Public access to Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are trying to enable public access for our SQL database. For this saving "`Selected Network`" option available under SQL server's "`Networking -> Public Access`" tab. When we click on save its getting saved but as soon as we revisit "`Public Access`" tag to verify the changes, by default "`Disable`" option is selected.
Here is the reference while saving the changes.

**After saving changes, bottom's save button is disabled**
[image]

**When we revisit "Public Access" tab, by default "Disable" is enabled again**
[image]
Can you please guide what could be wrong and any possible alternative for this?

Comment: Check is the update was saved correctly. There is a notification tab on the top right which will tell you this. It will also tell you what was the error, It is possible that a company policy is stopping you from allowing public access to a SQL DB.

Answer (score 1):

Once you specify "Selected Networks", you either need to add a virtual network rule under the "Virtual Networks" section, o you need to specify a public IP address on the Firewall Rules section by making a click on the "Add your client IP address ..." button (that is the public IP address of your current location, home or office) or by making a click on "Add a firewall rule" to specify other IP addresses that can access the server.

Please go to the Azure SQL logical server:

[image]

Select Networking on the left panel.

[image]

Now add the firewall rule.

[image]

[image]

If after following the steps outlined above you still get the same error, an Azure Policy may have been created that is blocking you to configure rules on Azure SQL firewall.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Tied this too, even if "Selected Networks" is checked and after adding client IP it gives an error popup. in popup error says - ""content":{"error":{"code":"DenyPublicEndpointEnabled","message":"Unable to create or modify firewall rules when public network interface for the server is disabled. To manage server or database level firewall rules, please enable the public network interface."}},"contentLength":253}"

Comment: Don't give up. I updated my instructions. Please follow them.

Comment: Thanks buddy, trying same but same issue. Looks like something to do with my Office's network settings? I have tried from my personal account on personal laptop and its working fine, only not working from office's Network it seems.

Comment: It seems an Azure Policy was created in your organization that prevents creation of Public IP addresses. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/effects

Comment: Ohh. So no way we can query on Azure database? It is not even authenticating using Active Directory when we tried to access form "Query Editor"

Comment: To make use the Query Editor you need to Allow access to Azure Services on the firewall. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61805629/i-cannot-access-azure-sql-database-using-query-editor-however-i-can-access-it-u/61811038#61811038

Comment: It ended up bein on same tab to enable it and giving same exceptions :(. Will check with our network team

Comment: Don't waste more time on it. Talk to them as you mentioned, they probably created a policy that is blocking you.